# Changing automatic vba code to manual start

Tags: excel, vba

I have this vba code which starts and runs on itself everytime data updated.

```
Function CM(r As Range, c As Range, d As Range) As Integer
    Dim lR As Long

    CM = 0

    For lR = d.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(d.Rows(lR), r) > 0 And Application.CountIf(d.Rows(lR - 1), c) > 0 Then CM = CM + 1
    Next lR
End Function
```

Is it possible to make it start manually going through F8, selecting the macro and start it? I am not sure why it is made this way. thanks.

Comment: This is a function. The function starts when something calls it - either form a cell or from another sub or function. If you want to debug it, just put a [break point](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/breakpoints.htm) to the beginning. If you don't want it to run, remove references to this function from the workbook or the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Or turn off calculations in the workbook, and manually run calculation when you need it.

Comment: Do you know what is calling it?  If it is constantly running then it is on an event listener like worksheet selection change.  You can move the code to a button, a macro, a custom ribbon event, or you can bind it to a key, so yes you can manually invoke it.  Depends what you are after.  open developer and search your project for the use of CM and take out its calling code and move it to a manual method.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I don't know what's calling it. All I have is this code on the worksheet.  I can't say if it 's on an event listener. It's not running constantly, it stops once it runs through the data,  I just don't have any control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_functions.htm

The only reason I am writing this as an answer is to show you this:

[image]

You can call functions form the immediate windows to test their outputs. This is a very powerful tool and i suggest you play around with it to get familiar with it. I tend to use this many times throughout the day due to some of the Access applications i have to support.

To view the immediate window hit Control+G.

*** added note *** If you need to test your function remember the input parameters are ranges so each pass value should look something like:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Yoursheetname").Range("yourrange")
```

I hope this helps you quite a bit!

Comment: Thanks,Doug for your suggestions.